# Selecting fields from second table in left join

Tags: sql

The fields c.Mcc and c.Mnc in outer select are not getting populated eventhough I have those fields in bd:RawDebug.CarrierDetails.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
 SELECT d.Id, d.DebugReason, d.DebugData, d.d1, d.d2, c.Mcc, c.Mnc
 FROM 
 (SELECT 
 Id, DebugReason, DebugData, 
 INTEGER(SUBSTR(DebugData,0,3)) AS d1, 
 SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE(DebugData,'[^a-zA-Z0-9]',' '),4,LENGTH(DebugData)-3) as d2
 FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([bd:RawDebug.T],TIMESTAMP('2016-05-16'),TIMESTAMP('2016-05-16'))
 WHERE DebugReason = 50013 and Id = 550661626 LIMIT 50) AS d
 LEFT JOIN
 (
   SELECT Network, Mcc, STRING(Mnc) as Mnc from [bd:RawDebug.CarrierDetails]
 ) AS c
 ON c.Mcc = d.d1 and c.Mnc = d.d2
 LIMIT 50
```

Comment: when you using `left outer join`, the fields in the right table could be `NULL`. For a test, you should add `where c.MCC is not null` before `limit 50` and see if result have it

Comment: It could be a case that you have those fields in the CarrierDetails but the join is looking for items from that select of d which if i am not mistaken is limited by a single Id - 550661626.

Comment: For Id = 550661626, I get d.d1 as 310 and d.d2 as 410. In CarrierDetails table, I have an entry form Mcc = 310 and Mnc = 410. But I wonder why c.Mcc and c.Mnc are not getting populated.

Comment: @Chris: In RawDebug.T, I have an Id 550661626 for which DebugData is 310410?. There is no common fields between RawDebug.T and RawDebug.CarrierDetails. Hence, I have u used a substring function to get d1 as 310 and d2 as 410. In CarrierDetails, I have an entry for Mcc = 310 and Mnc = 410. But c.Mcc and c.Mnc does not get printed. Since there are no common fields, I wonder whether there is a best way to achieve the desired results.

Comment: Do you have a record within the first 50 results of CarrierDetails where mcc = 310 and mnc = 410 ?

Comment: @Chris: For this query, the table returns 1 record:

SELECT * FROM [RawDebug.CarrierDetails] 
WHERE Mcc=310 and Mnc = 410
LIMIT 50

Answer (score 0):

If `c.Mcc` and `c.Mnc` are `NULL` in your results, yet that have a value in the `[bd:RawDebug.CarrierDetails]` table, then the only explanation is the LEFT JOIN criteria.  You should look again at the condition `ON c.Mcc = d.d1 and c.Mnc = d.d2` and ensure this really does match with your data in `[bd:RawDebug.CarrierDetails]`